# Efficient OData batch

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, odata

I have a simple controller.. Assume, my clients needs to send multiple requests (Batch) and say each request on server side takes a second.. If the client sends 100 requests in a batch, the controller will be executed 100 times on server.. This is not very efficient. Is there a different way to implement batch, so the controller can get all the 100 requests from client in a single shot , process them and return the results?

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TeachersController : ControllerBase
{
    List<Teacher> teachers = new List<Teacher> { new Teacher { Id = 1, Name = "t1" }, new Teacher { Id = 2, Name = "t2" } };        

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async ValueTask<ActionResult<Teacher>>  GetTeacher(int id)
    {

        foreach (var t in this.teachers)
        {
            if (t.Id == id)
            {
                return Ok(t);
            }
        }
        return NotFound();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    public ActionResult<IQueryable<Teacher>> GetTeachers()
    {
        return Ok(this.teachers);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rajiv, have you considered using Asynchronous.  Asynchronous APIs allow a small pool of threads to handle thousands of concurrent requests by not waiting on blocking calls.

Comment: Have you considered to load balance your service? every service has a limit on the number of requests that it can serve, so there must be a load balancer that is able to created more instances of your service and distribute the load equally on them

Comment: To start with, you can improve the performance of the first method by replacing it with the following 2 lines:
if (!this.teachers.Any(m => m.Id == id)) return NotFound();    |      
return Ok(this.teachers.First(m => m.Id == id))